# ActiveRecord: Multiple foreign keys to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm struggling a little on how to structure some data in Rails 3.

I have a table called `Tasks` and a table called `Todos`. A Todo can have up to 4 tasks, that are organized into the table like so:

Todos table:

- id
- todoname
- slot1
- slot2
- slot3
- slot4

Tasks table:

- id
- name
- description
- button_text
- button_url

In the Todos table, slot1 through slot4 would have the ID of the associated task. I'm unsure how to structure the associations in the models.

Simple old `has_many :tasks` and `belongs_to :todos` don't quite work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :limit => 4
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo
end


resources :todos do
  resources :tasks
end
```

To get the 4 tasks for a `@todo`, you would do `@todo.tasks`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks through :slots, :limit=>4
end
class Slot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todos
  belongs_to :tasks
end
```